# Erro: 'could not read Username for 'https://github.com' ao fazer push

Tags: git, github

Tenho um projeto em ASP.NET versionado no GitHub e ao tentar fazer um *push* é retornado o seguinte erro:

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Removi a tag, `asp.net` porque o problema é com o GIT ou o GitHub, não tem relação nenhuma com o projeto ser ASP.NET.

Comment: Qual a versão do GIT?

Comment: Falta colocar o comando de push completo

Comment: Não tem comando push completo, na verdade estou utilizando o plugin de github para visual studio, quando faço com o git na mão funciona normalmente.

Comment: Então provavelmente seja configuração do plugin, nada a ver com o git em si. Leia a documentação do plugin, acerca das configurações, e veja se deixou de fazer algum passo.

Comment: Pode sim, ter a ver com o Git... É preciso atualizar para a última versão por uma questão de seguraça.
Faça isso e teste novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Este [erro ocorre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274484/fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-device-not-configured) quando o `git` precisa perguntar o nome do usuário e senha, porém o único mecanismo de pedir pelo usuário e senha é o console e **não há um console disponível**.

Isto normalmente ocorre quando você está usando algum software por cima do `git` (no seu caso, creio que seria o Visual Studio) e tem algo incorreto ou faltando configurar na parte de credenciais.

Você pode resolver o problema da seguinte maneira:

1. Usar o [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) e guardar usuário/senha na própria configuração do Git.
2. Você também pode conferir como está o usuário e senha se optou pelo gerenciador do Windows. Assim: Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials -> abaixo de Generic Credentials -> atualizar/remover as credenciais. Exemplo: git:https://xxx.visualstudio.com
3. Usar SSH ao invés de HTTPS, configurando uma chave SSH na sua máquina e colocando ela na sua conta Github.
4. Também [há relatos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48976784/2387977) que este erro pode ocorrer por problemas do próprio software que faz interface com o Git (SourceTree, Visual Studio, etc). Experimente atualizá-lo também.

Se não estiver usando ferramenta alguma, [tente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38237165/2387977) usar este comando no console e tente novamente fazer o `push`:

```
env GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
```